# Как заменить TabView при клике на кнопку (SwiftUI)?

Tags: ios, swiftui

У меня есть `NavigationView` с `EditButton()`. При нажатии на копку `edit`, `TabView` должен заменится (с `NormalBar` на `EditBar`). Попробовал сделать глобальную переменную `editTabBar`, и смотреть её значение перед отрисовкой, но при изменении этой переменной, `switch editTabBar` никак не реагировал. Поставил его по умолчанию `true`, и понял, что даже если бы он реагировал, то не особо помогло, так как `RedView()` пропадает, если `editTabBar == true`.

Инициализация:

```
var body: some View {
    switch editTabBar {
    case false:
        return AnyView( NormalBar())
    case true:
        return AnyView( EditBar())
    }
}
```

TabViews:

```
struct NormalBar:View{
    var body: some View {

         TabView {
            RedView()
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: "phone.fill")
                    Text("First Tab")
            }
            BlueView()
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: "tv.fill")
                    Text("Second Tab")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct EditBar:View {
    var body: some View {

        TabView {
            tabItem {
                Image(systemName: "phone.fill")
                Text("select all")
            }
            tabItem {
                Image(systemName: "tv.fill")
                Text("delete all")
            }
        }

    }
}
```

RedView:

```
struct RedView: View {
@State private var items = ["Phil Swanson", "Karen Gibbons", "Grant Kilman", "Wanda Green"]

@State var selectKeeper = Set<String>()
@State private var editMode = EditMode.inactive
private static var count = 0

var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        List (items, id: \.self, selection: $selectKeeper){ name in
            Text(name)
        }.navigationBarTitle(Text("Update"), displayMode: .inline)
            .navigationBarItems(leading: EditButton(), trailing: addButton)
            .environment(\.editMode, $editMode)
    }
}
func onAdd() {
    items.append("Item #\(Self.count)")
    Self.count += 1

}
private var addButton: some View {
    switch editMode {
    case .inactive:
        editTabBar = false
        return AnyView(Button(action: onAdd) { Image(systemName: "plus") })
    default:
        editTabBar = true
        return AnyView(EmptyView())
    }
}
private func onDelete(offsets: IndexSet) {
    items.remove(atOffsets: offsets)
}
}
```

При нажатии на копку `edit`, `TabView` должен меняться, как в телеграмм, во вкладке "чаты", например. Или полная замена `TabView` это плохая идея и всегда будет сопровождаться исчезновением `NavigationView`? Тогда может скрыть этот `tabView`, а на его месте отрисовать кастомный элемент? Как лучше сделать?

Comment: не могли бы привести полный пример, который можно запустить, здесь нет части кода

Comment: @schmidt9 да, вот - https://pastebin.com/LRAc64Lm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я переписал ваш пример, изменив следующее.

- добавил кастомную панель с вкладками, так как `TabView` предназначено для переключения вью, а не для выполнения каких-то действий по нажатию (в данном случае действия в режиме редактирования)
- добавил кастомную кнопку редактирования, так как `EditButton` опять же не позволяет навесить кастомные нажатия
- добавил раздельную логику для верхней панели редактирования и переключения нижней панели
- для переключения используются биндинги

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @State var redViewSelected = true
    @State var editTabBar = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            if redViewSelected {
                RedView(editTabBar: $editTabBar)
            } else {
                BlueView()
            }

            if editTabBar {
                EditBar()
            } else {
                NormalBar(redViewSelected: $redViewSelected)
            }

        }
    }

    // MARK: Bars

    struct NormalBar: View {

        @Binding var redViewSelected: Bool

        var body: some View {

            HStack {
                Button(action: {
                    self.redViewSelected = true
                }, label: {
                    VStack(spacing: 4) {
                        Image(systemName: "phone.fill")
                        Text("First Tab")
                    }
                }).frame(maxWidth: .infinity)

                Button(action: {
                    self.redViewSelected = false
                }, label: {
                    VStack(spacing: 4) {
                        Image(systemName: "tv.fill")
                        Text("Second Tab")
                    }
                }).frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
            }

        }
    }

    struct EditBar: View {
        var body: some View {

            HStack {
                Button(action: {
                    // TODO: implement
                }, label: {
                    VStack(spacing: 4) {
                        Image(systemName: "phone.fill")
                        Text("select all")
                    }
                }).frame(maxWidth: .infinity)

                Button(action: {
                    // TODO: implement
                }, label: {
                    VStack(spacing: 4) {
                        Image(systemName: "tv.fill")
                        Text("delete all")
                    }
                }).frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
            }

        }
    }

    // MARK: Views

    struct RedView: View {

        @Binding var editTabBar: Bool

        @State private var items = ["Phil Swanson", "Karen Gibbons", "Grant Kilman", "Wanda Green"]

        @State var selectKeeper = Set<String>()
        @State private var editMode = EditMode.inactive
        private static var count = 0

        var body: some View {
            NavigationView {
                List (items, id: \.self, selection: $selectKeeper){ name in
                    Text(name)
                }.navigationBarTitle(Text("Update"), displayMode: .inline)
                    .navigationBarItems(leading: editButton, trailing: addButton)
                    .environment(\.editMode, $editMode)
            }
        }

        func onAdd() {
            items.append("Item #\(Self.count)")
            Self.count += 1

        }

        private var editButton: some View {
            Button(action: {
                self.editMode.toggle()
                self.editTabBar.toggle()
            }) {
                Text(self.editMode.title)
            }
        }

        private var addButton: some View {
            switch editMode {
            case .inactive:
                // Causes "Modifying state during view update, this will cause undefined behavior."
                // self.editTabBar = false
                return AnyView(Button(action: onAdd) { Image(systemName: "plus") })
            default:
                // self.editTabBar = true
                return AnyView(EmptyView())
            }
        }

        private func onDelete(offsets: IndexSet) {
            items.remove(atOffsets: offsets)
        }
    }

    struct BlueView: View {
        @State private var demoData = ["Phil Swanson", "Karen Gibbons", "Grant Kilman", "Wanda Green"]
        @State var selectKeeper = Set<String>()

        var body: some View {
            NavigationView {
                List(demoData, id: \.self, selection: $selectKeeper){ name in
                    Text(name)
                }
                .navigationBarItems(trailing: EditButton())
                .navigationBarTitle(Text("Selection Demo \(selectKeeper.count)"))
            }
        }
    }
}

extension EditMode {
    var title: String {
        self == .active ? "Done" : "Edit"
    }

    mutating func toggle() {
        self = self == .active ? .inactive : .active
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```